# Adding Color bars from print production

Tags: printing, crop, cropmarks

Using the `crop` package, we can easily add printer marks. I am look for **[Color Bars](https://printninja.com/printing-resource-center/printing-academy/pre-press-production/printers-marks)**.

[image]

I am wondering if there is a package for this?
[image]

Comment: It would be great if you could  show us what you have tried. Posting a [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) that indicates what you are trying to do makes it easier for people to understand what you want. It also makes it easier for people to help you, since they have some code to start from, and hence much more likely that some one will try to help you.

Comment: @Andrew I have only **looked** and **searched** in this case, as I can't seem to find any related package that does tihs.

Comment: @Andrew That looks exactly like what I was looking for !!